# MVC Razor @section doesn't understand Scripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have:

- VS 2013
- MVC 5.2.2
- Razor 3.2.2

Let me know if there's anything else you need to know.

This problem only happens on one view page.

I have a View with all HTML tags closed off properly

It's your standard view...

```
@model MyNameSpace.Models.Inquiry

@{
    var hasFormSetup = Model != null && Model.FormSetup != null && Model.FormSetup.Count > 0;
    if (hasFormSetup)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = Model.FormSetup[0].InquiryValue;
    }
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutInquiry.cshtml";
}

<style scoped>
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
</style>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        etc...
    </div>
    <div class="container" >
        etc...
    </div>

}


@section Scripts
{

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

    etc...

            });


    </script>
}
```

but...

on the line

```
@section Scripts
```

Resharper reports: "Cannot resolve section Scripts"

When I run, I get the exception:

```
Source: System.Web.WebPages
Target: Void VerifyRenderedBodyOrSections()
Type:   HttpException
Message:    The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutInquiry.cshtml": "Scripts".
Stack:     at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.VerifyRenderedBodyOrSections()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   etc...
```

No other page has this issue.

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Does your `_LayoutInquiry.cshtml` page have a `Scripts` section? Please add that file to your question. It should have `@RenderSection("Scripts", false)` at an appropriate location inside it. (The message says it all: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutInquiry.cshtml": "Scripts".)

Comment: omg. I feel like such a doofus. Please add this as an answer and I'll give you the points... You know what it does when this happens? You get the entire body duplicated without any data source - so your default error page shows up at the bottom of your page...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The exception message says:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutInquiry.cshtml": "Scripts".

This suggests that your `_LayoutInquiry.cshtml` page does not setup a placeholder for a `Scripts` section. You can do this by adding `@RenderSection("Scripts", false)` to your layout page in the appropriate location, where the `false` indicates that views may optionally supply this section.

Now, when your view renders, the contents of `@section Scripts { ... }` in your view will be rendered into the location of the `@RenderSection("Scripts", false)` call in your layout page.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue but using Rider instead of VS. The code was actually legit, but some cache got in the way.

So the solution was to "*Invalidate and Restart*" - found in `File > Invalidate caches...`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For others that may end up here. Everything is working OK but ReSharper complains about Section and Styles missing.

Our case was that we had _Layout.cshtml and _Layout.Mobile.cshtml in the shared folder.

Comment: Having this in a ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, I both tried to put the "_Layout.cshtml" directly in the "Views" folder as well as in the "Views/Shared" folder with no success. Still Resharper complaining (in my case it was Rider but shouldn't matter).

Comment: Try not using "." in the name of the second layout replace with "_" instead

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it is related to [having a RCL and a "\_Layout.cshtml" in both the web application _and_ the RCL](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-481899).