# How to use jQuery DataTables in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I am trying to use jQuery DataTables with Bootstrap in mvc 5 its not working properly but its working good in HTML and asp.net

MVC Code :

```html
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').dataTable();

        });
    </script>
}
```

Below is the output that I am getting

[image]

but same code if I am trying to do in asp.net output is good

[image]

My script references

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Why it is not working?

Comment: What does the .net table look like?

Comment: do you mean you're trying to use jquery datatable in mvc?

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in you browsers console?

Comment: It looks like the javascript code is not executing. Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168593/mvc-razor-section-doesnt-understand-scripts